# base 64 decode and write to doc file

Tags: java, base64, apache-poi, filewriter

I have a base64 encoded String . Which looks like this

```
UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDhD46/jQEAACkGAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA .
```

I decodeD the String and write it to word file using `FileWriter`. But When I tried opening the doc file i get an error saying corrupt data.

I would like to know what are the steps I need to follow to write the content to a word document after decoding the data . below is the code what I did and went wrong.

```
     byte[] encodedBytes = stringBase64.getBytes();
     byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes);
     String decodeString = new String(decodedBytes);
     filewriter = new java.io.FileWriter("F:\xxx.docx”);
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
     bw.write(decodeString);
```

Comment: Did you close the buffered writer after writing i.e. bw.close()?

Comment: try closing the file after writing data, bw.close();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decoded data isn't plain text data - it's just binary data. So write it with a `FileStream`, not a `FileWriter`:

```
// If your Base64 class doesn't have a decode method taking a string,
// find a better one!
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(stringBase64);
// Note the try-with-resources block here, to close the stream automatically
try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("F:\\xxx.doc")) {
    stream.write(decodedBytes);
}
```

Or even better:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(stringBase64);
Files.write(Paths.get("F:\\xxx.doc"), decodedBytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look.

```
    byte[]   encodedBytes = /* your encoded bytes*/

 // Decode data on other side, by processing encoded data
    byte[] decodedBytes= Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes );

    String yourValue=new String(decodedBytes);
    System.out.println("Decoded String is " + yourValue);
```

Now further you can write this string into a file and read further.

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.